# `docker rmi` tries to delete image with empty string (that does not exist)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I'm trying to delete **any** of my images, docker does that thing :

```
$ docker rmi 5aeb37c1fd00
Error response from daemon: image ID '' is invalid
Error: failed to remove images: [5aeb37c1fd00]
```

as you can see, it is complaining about an image with empty string name that it cannot delete.
If it matters, my docker is installed on vagrant machine with Red Hat 64-bit OS.
That error came by from yesterday. 2-3 days ago everything worked perfectly.

more additional information:

```
$ docker version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try forcing it. `docker rmi -f <image_id>`

Comment: just close it. I just deleted all the local docker data storage (containers directory, etc.) and downloaded the images again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just close it. I just deleted all the local docker data storage (containers directory, etc.) and downloaded the images again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in older docker versions. The error message is misleading.  I suggest you upgrade to the latest version of docker, the bug has been fixed.